# Creating PDF with TCPDF shows Undefined index: cols in tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 16928

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I wanted to use TCPDF to generate a PDF report. but every time it shows me error on line 16928 and I can't understand what to do...
It would be great if you could help me

here is my code:

```
<?php
$html = "
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='form.css'>
</head>

<body>
<div class='header'>
    <h4>وزارت بهداشت، درمان و آموزش کشور</h4>
    <h4>Ministry of Health & Medical Education</h4>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class='engterm'>University of medical science:</td><td class='val'>[SAMPLE_ECHO]</td><td class='perterm'>دانشگاه علوم پزشکی:</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='engterm'>Medical center:</td><td class='val'>[SAMPLE_ECHO]</td><td class='perterm'>مرکز پزشکی آموزشی درمانی:</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class='body'>
    <table class='main' border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td class='main' colspan='1' rowspan='2' style='text-align: left;'>
                <table style='margin: 0 auto;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='engterm'>Clinic no.:</td><td class='val'>[sample]</td><td class='perterm'>شماره درمانگاهی:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class='main' colspan='2' rowspan='2' style='text-align: center; width: 50%'>
                <h4>برگ خلاصه پرونده</h4>
                <h4>Unit Summery Sheet</h4>
            </td>
            <td class='main' colspan='1' rowspan='2' style='direction: ltr;'>
                <table style='margin: 0 auto;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='engterm'>Unit no.:</td><td class='val'>[sample]</td><td class='perterm'>شماره پرونده:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr></tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='main' rowspan='1'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td>Attending Physician:</td><td>SampleData</td><td>پزشک معالج:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class='main' rowspan='2'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <tr><td>Ward:</td><td>Sample</td><td>بخش:</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Room:</td><td>Sample</td><td>اتاق:</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Bed:</td><td>Sample</td><td>تخت:</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class='main' rowspan='1'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td>Name:</td><td>Sample</td><td>نام:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class='main' rowspan='1'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td>Family name:</td><td>Sample</td><td>نام خانوادگی:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='main'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td>Admission date:</td><td>Sample</td><td>تاریخ پذیرش:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class='main'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td>Date of Birth:</td><td>Sample</td><td>تاریخ تولد:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class='main'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td>Father's name:</td><td>Sample</td><td>نام پدر:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='main'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td></td><td>Sample</td><td>تاریخ ترخیص:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class='main'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td>Occupation:</td><td>Sample</td><td>شغل:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class='main'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td>Marriage status:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='radio' name='marriage_status' value='married'>متاهل / Married<br>
                        <input type='radio' name='marriage_status' value='single'>مجرد / Single
                    </td>
                    <td>وضعیت تاهل:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class='main'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td>Sex:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='radio' name='sex' value='male'>مرد / Male<br>
                        <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female'> زن / Female
                    </td>
                    <td>جنسیت:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td colspan='1' style='text-align: left;'>Address:</td><td colspan='2'>Sample</td><td colspan='1' style='text-align: right;'>آدرس:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td colspan='1'>Final Diagnosis:</td>
                    <td colspan='2'>Sample</td>
                    <td colspan='1'>تشخصی نهایی:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td colspan='1'>Medical & Surgical Procedures:</td>
                    <td colspan='2'>Sample</td>
                    <td colspan='1'>اقدامات درمانی و اعمال جراحی:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td colspan='1'>Results of Paraclinical Examination:</td>
                    <td colspan='2'>Sample</td>
                    <td colspan='1'>پاراكلينيكي آزمايشات نتايج:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td colspan='1'>Disease Progress (Cause of Death):</td>
                    <td colspan='2'>Sample</td>
                    <td colspan='1'>سیر بیماری (درصورت فوت، علت مرگ):</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td colspan='1'>Patient's Condition on Discharge:</td>
                    <td colspan='2'>Sample</td>
                    <td colspan='1'>وضعیت بیمار هنگام ترخیض:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td colspan='1'>Recommendations after discharge:</td>
                    <td colspan='2'>Sample</td>
                    <td colspan='1'>توصیه‌های پس از ترخیض:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table class='data'>
                    <td colspan='1'>Attending Physician's Name & Signature:</td>
                    <td colspan='2'>Sample</td>
                    <td colspan='1'>نام و امضا پزشک معالج:</td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>";

require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('htmlout.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

When reading the page from web server, it shows me the following error:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: cols in /home/aien/public_html/Arash.Sammak/JSON Return/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 16928
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a valid `<thead>` element to every table. `TCPDF` parses the `<thead>` element to determine the number of columns in a table when it outputs tables in PDF.

Also, check your HTML twice is valid or not if some other errors keep occurring.

Hope this helps.